# what does U \ {v} means?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, set-theory

I am trying to learn the minimum dominating set problem and the algorithm says

1. U ← V
2. While there exists some v ∈ U such that, U \ {v} dominates G2 do
   Remove v from U.
3. Output U.

What does the symbol \ means?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation). So $U \setminus \{v\} = \{ u \in U : u \neq v\}$.

Comment: Got it thank you